# Convert string to 2 dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have a string which is loaded from a .mat file and is in the following format :

```
(array([172.169, 73.2]), array([128.83, 102.31]), array([143.49, 124.43]), array([186.83, 95.69]), 'R', array([], dtype=float64))
```

Is there any way I can convert this directly to a numpy 2D array without parsing over the entire string and removing the "arrays" manually? Neither `numpy.fromstring` nor `numpy.frombuffer` will work here.

Comment: If it's a string, why have you not surrounded it with quotes?

Comment: is the 'R' a typo?

Comment: @DavidBuck It's similar, but not exactly, since to convert it to a list I have to parse the string anyways.

Comment: @Back2Basics No, R is not a typo. This is an annotation file for hands. R indicates the file is for the right hand. It's not to be there in the final array, I can manually remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `np.fromstring` with a regular expression:

```
import re

# s is your string
np.fromstring(', '.join(re.findall(r'\[(.+?)\]', s)), sep =', ').reshape((2, 2, 2))
```

output:

```
array([[[172.169,  73.2  ],
        [128.83 , 102.31 ]],

       [[143.49 , 124.43 ],
        [186.83 ,  95.69 ]]])
```